# Is there a way to check if a discord account token is valid or not?

Tags: javascript, regex, discord.js, token

As the title says, I'm trying to create a script that will check if a discord account token (not a bot token) is valid or not. I've tried regex matching like this:

```js
/^(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[^\w\s]\S{5,}$/g.test(token)
```

but I don't think this is the best method, and I feel like some tokens can slip through the net if I use this sort of detection method to check if they're valid.

Comment: what constitutes a "valid" token?

Comment: You may have to make an API request attempting to use the token, and assuming false on an error.

Comment: @Bravo basically a discord account token where you can interact with the discord API

Comment: @EliRichardson I thought of that but I'm not sure how to implement it, interacting an API without any existing npm package is my weakpoint in js programming.

Comment: @Existentialist - I know what a token is, I want to know what you believe a **valid** token is, i.e. what do you think that regex is doing, and why do you think it may not be right (it doesn't seem to be a valid regex for a start)

Comment: @Existentialist are you unable to use any npm packages? I assume you could try to authenticate with discord.js and see if it works.

Comment: @Bravo oh, my bad. I'm, trying to validate a token that looks like this `mca.FWNsqEFvrw4pxvRXoEww2cxN3dEsUBIsP0Re7lS6i-LTNLfjEzAiFbwxf4z__DFRAEWGf5xEvVDnL5NEWWZ8Q`. I wanted to test if the token contains at least lowercase and uppercase letters, numbers, symbols such as ".", "-", and "_", and that's pretty much it. Rather than using regex matching, I might switch to using some authentication method with the discord API at the end though.

Comment: so a token must contain lowercase AND uppercase AND numbers AND . AND - AND _? are you sure? everything after the `mca.` looks as if it could be just url safe base64 ... so it may not contain ALL those things every time

Comment: Btw Discord Accounts are not allowed to interact with the API through software other than the offical client, this question probably has malicious in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex for a token with mfa protection is `/mfa\.[\w-]{84}/`, without mfa protection is `/[\w-]{24}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{27}/`.

Then you can check it using discord api with the token in Authorization header

Comment: thanks! Can I also ask what mfa is exactly? I realised my token starts with `mfa.` but I assumed it was just part of the token identifier value itself.

Comment: @Existentialist basically is 2FA, with Google Authenticator or via sms

Answer (score 2):

`Use something along the lines of this for token validation`

```
const tokenRegex = /(mfa\.[\w-]{84}|[\w-]{24}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{27})/;
const isValid = token.match(tokenRegex);

if (isValid) { /* Code to execute */ } else { console.error("Invalid Token!") }



/
```