# Token Finder (in a good way)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a discord bot that when someone sends a discord token, bot token, or bot secret, it automatically deletes the message. I think the pattern bot tokens follow is:

1. It contains two periods
2. Starts with "OTc"
3. Contains numbers

How could I make it scan for the other two?

Comment: This answer might help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166596/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-discord-account-token-is-valid-or-not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166596/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-discord-account-token-is-valid-or-not)

Comment: Discord already warns users when they submit a message with a potential token included.  If they still want to send it they need to explicitly confirm. This means there's a high chance that you'd end up deleting messages that the user wants to send because it looks like (or is - could be invalid) a token.... Just something to consider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple pre-existing bot with a RegEx pattern. I also found a chart showing how tokens are generated so that might help with your quest.

[image]
*Credit to [hxr404/Discord-Console-hacks](https://github.com/hxr404/Discord-Console-hacks) on GitHub*