# Discord tokens Regex

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord.net, pycord

## My issue:

> I have a trouble getting my discord token, I tried to get it through APPDATA. But to do that I need the REGEX for it. I already started coding it but I'm stuck finding the regex

## What I tried:

> the only known regex are: The regex for a token with mfa protection `/mfa\.[\w-]{84}/`, without mfa protection is `/[\w-]{24}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{27}/`. I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71166596/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-discord-account-token-is-valid-or-not) but after trying it, I found out that they are outdated and they are not working. That's why I came here to ask for the REGEX token for Discord Tokens

## Discord token format:

> There is two types of formats. One with authentication enabled, example: `OTk0MeQ3MDgxMjk0Njg0MjQw.LqsoPU.OeISfrT8o4SoLoPE7IPaIFWdOPa8PXOR8esdoO`.
>
> And another format with authentication disabled, example:
> `MTAwMzQyMDO0ozQ2O7g3MzM3Pf.E84Oip.80oOjExirQOPso5_Os8EoSoKwsEXAo9vMEp01s`

Comment: Keep in mind that to get precise answer almost certainly you need to include sample of raw source data and specify string part you want to parse. Not everyone knows format of message with "discord token" you got from somewhere.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Try to press [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76498176/edit) and paste there source string and expected result. Replace your token with something similar to avoid data leak.

Comment: I don't know anything about Discord tokens, but I noticed the regexes accept only `[\w-]` in them, while your example token has _ .So try `[\w-_]` .

Comment: @BoppreH, by adding the `_` in `[\w-_]`, I get an error. The error is: `re.error: bad character range \w-_ at position 22`

Comment: @BoppreH, by adding the `\w`, I made it accepting digits, letters AND underscores (`_`).

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how I spent all these years without knowing that `\w` includes `_`. I thought it was just letters and numbers.

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us. So, do you have any idea of how can I fix my issue ?

Comment: @pydal1, isn't the bot's token to be copied from your Discord Developer Portal? Please be as specific as possible in what you're trying to do. If you're trying to get some other token, try to compare and form your own regex.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder I'm trying to get my own discord account token, from the Discord application. I can access it from files but I need the regex of it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting off with the non-mfa protected token
Based on just counting the characters in each section of the token, you'll notice that the last section doesn't exactly match what the regex pattern is trying to match.
`[\w-]{24}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{27}` this pattern is expecting 24 characters matching [\w-] followed by a '.' followed by 6x [\w-] followed by a '.' and ending off with 27x [\w-] - However, the token you've provided has 38 characters in the last section. With that in mind, this 27->38 change will fix the first one for you
`[\w-]{24}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{38}`

Why you're including dashes when no dashes are present in either example is questionable, and will increase the chance of matching something that isn't actually a discord token, should this be unintended.

In regards to the mfa-protected kind, the regex you've suggested will not do the job assuming the format you've provided is correct.
The provided example token

> MTAwMzQyMDO0ozQ2O7g3MzM3Pf.E84Oip.80oOjExirQOPso5_Os8EoSoKwsEXAo9vMEp01s

Your regex `mfa\.[\w-]{84}` is trying to match "mfa." followed by 84x[\w-]
As there's no "mfa." to be found anywhere in the provided token, we can go ahead and get rid of that part.
The provided token is 72 characters long, and contains '.' which cannot be matched by \w nor -
Therefore following the format of the previous regex pattern is probably the way to go here, and that would look like this
`[\w-]{26}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{38}`
Only difference from the previous one is 26 characters in the first section as opposed to 24. However due to the small sample size of examples, I'm not able to determine whether or not the index of the '_' underscore is always as shown here
In the case that it is, your regex should look something like this instead
`[\w-]{26}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{15}\_[\w-]{22}` once again dashes are present for no apparent reason, which if left in by mistake ultimately weakens this patterns ability to confidently match the provided examples

If you're interested in learning about regex, sites such as these are great tools to get a basic hands-on understanding

https://regexper.com/ 
https://regexr.com/

Comment: Hello @Tito, using the Provided regex, I'm still not able to find the Discord Token, the underscore isn't shown there. It could be shown everywhere. Sorry for the lack of examples. Let me know if you need one to help me, thanks for helping me!

Comment: Hello again, after doing some researches, putting my right discord token into the website that you provided, I've seen that the expression `[\w-]{26}\.[\w-]{6}\.[\w-]{38}` perfectly matches my real token. However, putting it on my code will not give me anything.

Comment: Perhaps your means of locating the token is the problem, or maybe discord tokens no longer use the provided format

Comment: It could even be the case that the token is encoded

Comment: for your first answer, I checked my Discord token, and it does use the provided format.

Comment: I think that Discord might have changed the emplacement of their tokens. Because I cannot find it in the file that I got. But I don't find the new emplacement (if they changed it) of the tokens, so they didn't change it.